# Using Parcel to only convert from es6 to es5 and minify

Tags: javascript, typescript, parcel

I have a setup like this

```
src/
- index.js (loads utils/file.js)
-/utils
--/file.js
```

After setting up parcel the output is great, however the output contains a loader (parcelRequire) and other utilities from Parcel which accounts for 98% of my application. Is there a setting to only have Parcel combine the files, convert from ES6 to ES5 and minify them without creating the helpers and loaders? I did have a similar setup for TypeScript and WebPack which worked great and I am migrating the application from TS to ES6.